# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' in data migration

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to copy data from posts table in table A to post table in database B. 
Database B has a blank post table whose schema is different from A.

Here is the query that I came up with:

```
INSERT INTO b.post (post_id, thread_id, user_id, username, post_date) SELECT 
                     postid,  threadid,  userid,  username, dateline FROM a.post;
```

But when I run the above command I get from mysql CLI ,

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

How should I fix this?

P.S. database b is for a fresh Xenforo forum and table a Vbulletin forum to be migrated. I don't mind override data on b, but obviously I'd like to keep the schema intact.

Comment: Before doing anything you need to find out _why_ you've got this error. Does `a.post` have this duplicate? Does `b.post` already have data in there? Do the tables have different structures? If they have different structures which one is correct?

Comment: Ben, two tables have different structures.

Comment: Can you also post the DDL of the two tables? Is the old postid/threadid important or would it work to give all posts new ids starting at 1?

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean by DDL. It is a mysql server on Linux.

Comment: @supermario: DDL = `CREATE TABLE` statements. DDL means *data definition language*. It's in contrast with DML, which means *data manipulation language*. DML = SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements.

Comment: @SuperMario . . . Do the posts in `b.posts` need to inherent the same postId that they have in `a.posts`?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the primary key constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

**`Edit`**

***but obviously I'd like to keep the schema intact.***

```
INSERT INTO b.post (post_id, thread_id, user_id, username, post_date) 
SELECT postid,  threadid,  userid,  username, dateline FROM a.post 
group by postid;
```

**Please Note: Some records will be missing as the post_id is a primary key**

Please read about **[Primary Key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)**

Comment: That is horrible advice... You should never remove the constraints enforcing integrity.

Comment: whould you elaborate how to do that?

Comment: @Ben ***P.S. table b belongs to a fresh forum. So I don't mind override data on it.***

Comment: Luv, please refer to completed P.S. :)

Comment: You're not overwriting data @Luv, you're ensuring that the relational integrity of your database is compromised. If there's data in `b.post` already that's not required the correct solution is to _delete_ it.

Comment: +1 Not such a  bad answer.  A column with duplicates is no candidate for a primary key.  You either have to remove the duplicates or remove the primary key.

Comment: This GROUP BY won't work. It is also pretty ugly to use it in order to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @ZombieHunter Its mysql my friend.

Comment: @Luv: You are right, this is a valid MySQL although its a pretty strange behavior. Thanks for the lesson.